# How to make a button invisible even when I refresh a page depending on a label content in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, button, xamarin.android, show-hide

When I click on the button it becomes hidden, however when I refresh the page it is still there. How to make it stay hidden depending on a content in a label?

```
 private void Button3_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            App.products[Index].Quantity++;
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            if (btn.IsVisible)
            { btn.IsVisible = false; }
            else
            {
                btn.IsVisible = false;

            }
        }
```

I want this Button to stay hidden when the page is refreshed depending on this value **App.products[Index].Quantity**. When I click on the Button it becomes from 0 to 1 and I want if it is not 0 the Button to be hidden.

Comment: please post the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In YourPage.xaml:

```xml
    <Button IsVisible={Binding ButtonIsVisible} ... />
```

In YourPage.xaml.cs:

```cs
public YourPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
    BindingContext = this;
}

// NOTE: `=>` not `=`. To be a property; expression evaluated every time it is needed.
public bool ButtonIsVisible => App.products[Index].Quantity == 0;

private void Button3_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.products[Index].Quantity++;
    // So xaml sees the change.
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ButtonIsVisible));
}
```

For more information, google `xamarin binding`.